# Is there a correct way to place React Hooks inside functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, refactoring

So what im asking is there some kind of style guide for writing react functional components with hooks. Sometimes I work with components which includes different kind of hooks:

- Simple React hooks like: useMemo, useCallback, ...
- Project custom React hooks like: useCategory, useProducts, ...
- Third-party React hooks like: useRouter, useMediaQuery, ...

Example (this is not my real code example, just for understanding):

```js
import React, { useMemo, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";

import { useCategory, useProducts} from "@hooks";

export const Category: React.FC<CategoryProps> = () => {
  const foo = useMemo(() => (
    // some logic here..
  ), []);

  const { query } = useRouter();

  const { category, loading: categoryLoading } = useCategory(query.slug);

  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ query: "(min-width: 1280px)" });

  const handleFoo = useCallback(() => {
    // some logic here...
  }, []);

  const { products, loading: productsLoading } = useProducts(category.id);

  useEffect(() => {
    // some logic here...
  }, []);


  return (<h1>Some big template here...</h1>);
}
```

I'm struggling to find some kind of information about how to place (sort) hooks inside components.
A few questions:

- Should third-party hooks go right at the start of component function body, or should be go last?
- Should useMemo hooks be above useEffect/useCallback hooks?
- Where should I place project custom hooks?

I know that is simple answer to that question is just to be consistent, but I want to know, what react community thinks, how you write your functional components with hooks?

Comment: Hooks have input arguments and return output values. If hooks do not depend on each other's values, you can place them in any order you like. But in many cases hooks do need the output values of other hooks as input and therefore the ordering of those is dictated by the program logic.
Mandating the order with a style guide is non-sensical.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the React Documentation, I found a couple rules in regards to hooks: [https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:~:text=Instead%2C%20always%20use%20Hooks%20at,multiple%20useState%20and%20useEffect%20calls](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:%7E:text=Instead%2C%20always%20use%20Hooks%20at,multiple%20useState%20and%20useEffect%20calls).

Also this article: https://blog.bitsrc.io/best-practices-with-react-hooks-69d7e4af69a7

The second articles gives a good list of best practices when it comes to React Hooks.

1.) Class based components have a more structured order do to all of the lifecycle methods that you are working with `componentDidMount` ect.

2.) When it comes to a functional component, then the order/structure really is not enforced. From the article:

> It’s recommended to first declare state variables with useState hook, then write the subscriptions with useEffect hook followed by any function relevant to the component’s job.
> Then finally, you return the elements to be rendered by the browser...

In other words, what makes sense you as a developer will probably be alright. If this is a project that you are doing with other developers. Developing a coding type standard based on your work might be a good idea.

Let me know if that answers your question :)

Comment: This is good answer, thank you. I'm wondering, maybe I can write some custom eslint rules for hooks order in my project, what do you think? Is this good idea? Or maybe there is better tool for this?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks <-- I would start your search here. And maybe perahps search through npm for a better one. But yes, this is something I do. My Eslint hanldes the sorting.